# Произведение наибольшего и наименьшего чисел, написал код, но выходит ошибка

Tags: c, алгоритм, циклы, ввод

Дана числовая последовательность чисел А1,А2,…. Признак конца ввода чисел является «+». Cоставить программу определяющую: произведение минимального и максимального числа последовательности.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

int n[10];
int max=n[0];
int min=n[0];
scanf("%d", &n);
do{
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
if(n[i] > max)
max = n[i];

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)

if(n[i] < min)
min = n[i];
}
while (n[10]!= '+');
printf("max: %d",max);
printf("min: %d",min);
printf("Result: %d", max * min);
}
```

Comment: Ошибка при выполнении, так? Скажите, а что вы хотите, если читаете только одно число? (`scanf("%d", &n);`) Если ваши переменные `max` и `min` получают не инициализированное значение (`n[0]` **до** того, как оно введено)? Если вы обращаетесь к несуществующему члену массива `n[10]`? И хотя формально сравнение `n[10]!= '+'` допустимо, вряд ли вы имеете в виду, что `n[10]` надо сравнивать с числом 43 (что происходит в коде)...

Comment: а как мне сделать так, чтобы при вводе чисел он их сравнивал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int max=n;
    int min=n;
    for(;;)
    {
        if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1)
        {
            if(n > max) max = n;
            else if(n < min) min = n;
        }
        else break;
    };
    printf("max: %d\n", max);
    printf("min: %d\n", min);
    printf("Result: %d\n", max * min);
}
```

Единственное - программа отреагирует окончанием ввода на любое *не число*, а не только на `+`. Это уж напишите сами...